# How to sort list of numbers into categories with specific cutoff?

Tags: bash, python

anybody can help with the way how to sort my numbers in different categories:

```
3.83
3.93
3.48
2.96
3.66
2.79
3.17
```

I want to find the way how to return the number of appearances, something like:

```
1.5-2: 0
2-2.5: 0
2.5-3.2: 3
3.2-4: 4
```

Comment: This seems vaguely on the edge of being 1) a homework problem, which depending on the day you may find various responses to and 2) is teetering on the edge of being related to Ubuntu at all.

Comment: No its not a homework, just something for personal use, I dont expect somebody to answer the question but to give a bit of clue how to do it. But its fine, thats you personal opinion and I got nothing against it, if you think this question is inappropriate you can vote for it to close.

Comment: This is a *histogram binning* problem. See for example [numpy.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html?highlight=histogram#numpy.histogram)

Comment: Great, you can put it in the answer as well, Ill give you a upvote as it was helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a histogram binning problem. In python, you can use the numpy `histogram` function, ex.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.histogram([3.83,3.93,3.48,2.96,3.66,2.79,3.17],[2,2.5,3.2,4])
(array([0, 3, 4]), array([ 2. ,  2.5,  3.2,  4. ]))
>>>
```

Documentation:

- [numpy.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`histogram.py` util](https://github.com/bitly/data_hacks), which includes an option for binning numbers in a custom list of buckets:

```
histogram.py --no-mvsd -m 1.5 -x 4 -B 2,2.5,3.2,4  <  numbers.txt
```

Output:

```
# NumSamples = 7; Min = 1.50; Max = 4.00
# each ∎ represents a count of 1
    1.5000 -     2.0000 [     0]: 
    2.0000 -     2.5000 [     0]: 
    2.5000 -     3.2000 [     3]: ∎∎∎
    3.2000 -     4.0000 [     4]: ∎∎∎∎
```

---

Note: the current version (*v0.3.1*) of the above util is a bit temperamental.     One might suppose `histogram.py --no-mvsd -B 1.5,2,2.5,3.2,4 < numbers.txt` would be sufficient, but the resulting output then omits the `0` count rows, printing only the two rows with `3` and `4`.  Adding a *min* `-m 1.5` and *max* `-x 4`, plus paring the `-B` list are needed to produce the desired output.